# Flat roof membrane not welded at edge of each layer, need help

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing

The roofing company I hired finished applying Polyfresko bitumen on my garage, and instead of welding the beginning and end of new layers at the edges, they overlapped one layer over another by about 6 inches, resulting in a “hump” of overlapping layers.

Is this normal? I thought the membrane would be completely flat. First example:

[image]

The overlap can be seen from the driveway:

[image]

Where one sheet ends, they overlapped the new sheet by about 6 inches instead of welding at the edge of the sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s not normal for the edges to be loose.

Poly glass is a self sealing modified bitumen roofing product. See here:

http://www.polyglass.com/public/COM/products/POLYFRESKO_G_SA.pdf

As you can see in Item #6 of the installation instructions, the seams are to be lapped 6” and side lapped 4”.

I think it’s installed correctly.

If there are loose edges you could have leaks, blow-off, etc. AND your warranty is void.

Comment: Op is not stating that the seams are loose.  He is asking if the edge should overlap 6" verse edge against edge butt seams.  I have no experience with the material under discussion, but I would guess that the overlaying makes a more water-tight seams.  like installing shingles on a roof.

Comment: @Programmer66 Oops...you’re right. See changes in my answer.